# Mock IEnumerable<T> using moq

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

Having this interface, how can I mock this object using moq?

```
public interface IMyCollection : IEnumerable<IMyObject>
{
    int Count { get; }
    IMyObject this[int index] { get; }
}
```

I get:

> can not convert expression type IEnumerable to IMyCollection

Comment: Why not just do an `IList<MyObject>`?

Comment: @ShaneKm Just so you are aware, as of .NET 4.5 there is a type built in to .NET [`IReadonlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) that does the exact contract you are trying to do and you get the benefit of it already being applied to built in types like `List<T>`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
var itemMock = new Mock<IMyObject>();
List<IMyObject> items = new List<IMyObject> { itemMock.Object }; //<--IEnumerable<IMyObject>

var mock = new Mock<IMyCollection>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Count).Returns(() => items.Count);
mock.Setup(m => m[It.IsAny<int>()]).Returns<int>(i => items.ElementAt(i));
mock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => items.GetEnumerator());
```

The mock will use the concrete `List` to wrap and expose the desired behavior for the test.

Comment: An year later, this saved my day! Thank you! +1

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Count, you need to use *SetupGet()*. In the case of the Indexer, use

```
mock.Setup(m => m[It.IsAny<int>()])
```

to return the desired value

Answer (score -1):

For my use cases I need to return an empty IEnumerable.

```
mockObj.Setup(x => x.EnumerateBlah()).Returns(Enumerable.Empty<MyType>);
```